# BigInteger exponentiation with negative number fails

Tags: java, biginteger, pow, exponentiation

I want to make numbers with negative exponents, how do I make them in Java? This is the formula I want to create in Java using BigInteger:

( k^**-1** * (m + x*r) ) mod q.

I made it like this:

```
int expo = -1;
BigInteger s = ( k.pow(expo).multiply(m.add(x.multiply(r))) ).mod(q);
```

When I run it, an error like this appears
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Negative exponent`

Comment: How about just divide `m + x*r` by `k`?

Comment: See [BigInteger.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow-int-). `BigInteger.pow` returns a `BigInteger`. But when exponent is negative, this would cause the operation to yield a non-integer value.

Comment: This looks like you need the modular inverse. The `modInverse()` method can be used for that.

Comment: Remember, your first stop is **always** the javadoc, which says: *ArithmeticException - exponent is negative. (This would cause the operation to yield a non-integer value.)* ... which leads to the fact that you dont need the negative number there,  ... as explained by the others: x ^ - whatever is the same as 1 / (x ^ whatever )

Comment: This seems to be really a math question, not a programming question. I assume the reason you want to do a calculation like this is something to do with cryptography. The short answer is that division (and thus exponentiation by negative numbers) works kinda differently in modulo-k contexts than it does normally.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question create or accept an answer instead please.